# Access Windows Registry from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-registry

Is there any way I can access registry of my Windows 7 installation from Ubuntu. I believe that Registry Editor is a GUI to edit various configuration settings which are stored and distributed among multiple files. So I wonder if I can access those configuration from Ubuntu (or any other non-windows OS).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `chntpw` tool has (very basic) registry editing capabilities.

Also try the `regedit` that comes with Wine – you might be able to load the Win7 registry hives into it. The files are:

- Registry: **`HKLM\SYSTEM`**

  File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\system`
- Registry: **`HKLM\SOFTWARE`**

  File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\software`
- Registry: **`HKU\<user-SID>`** (aka **`HKCU`**)

  File: `<home>\NTUSER.DAT`
- Registry: **`HKU\<user-SID>_Classes`** (aka **`HKCU\Software\Classes`**)

  File: `<home>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat`

  File: `<home>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\usrclass.dat` – as of Windows Vista
- Registry: **`HKU\.DEFAULT`** (the system account)

  File: `\WINDOWS\system32\config\default`

Note that `HKU\.DEFAULT` is the **system** account. It is not the template account.

The template account's files are at `\Documents and Settings\Default User` (substitute for `<home>` above).

[self todo: SECURITY, SAM]

Comment: is ti possible to edit any other registry zones, @grawity? For example, I would like to edit an entry inside `HKEY_USERS`.

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez: Yeah, that's the same as the 3rd bullet point above (HKCU is an alias for HKU\currentuserid). I'll update later with paths for HKU\.default and HKU\currentuserid_Classes.

Comment: Location for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP?

Answer (score 5):

[Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) has a registry editor which works under Linux

> - There is also a registry editor and other registry utilities that works
>     under linux/unix, and can be used for
>     other things than password editing

Answer (score 4):

### A. [reglookup](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/reglookup.1.html)

apt install `reglookup`

```sh
$ reglookup -t BINARY -p \
  /ControlSet001/Services/BTHPORT/Parameters/Keys/4c1d96a0c133/c8478c0b5dd0 \
  /mnt/win10/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM

PATH,TYPE,VALUE,MTIME
/ControlSet001/Services/BTHPORT/Parameters/Keys/4c1d96a0c133/c8478c0b5dd0,BINARY,%A6%06%9A%01-l%1CI%051%97%86%E3%98g\,
```

it show binary as % encoded string, not like `regedit`.

// a js function, to decode it's output // can be run in browser F12 console

```js
function my_decode(val){
  var out = []
  val.match(/%..|./g,'').forEach(function(v){
    var hex = v[0]=='%' ? v.substr(1) : v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    out.push(hex)
  })
  return out.join(',')
}

//usage
my_decode('%A6%06%9A%01-l%1CI%051%97%86%E3%98g\\')
"A6,06,9A,01,2d,6c,1C,49,05,31,97,86,E3,98,67,5c"
```

or

```js
unescape('%A6%06%9A%01-l%1CI%051%97%86%E3%98g\\')
  .replace(/./g, (x) => ('0'+x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-2)+',')
  .replace(/,$/,'')
"a6,06,9a,01,2d,6c,1c,49,05,31,97,86,e3,98,67,5c"
```

### B. [reged](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/reged.8.html)

apt install `chntpw`

```sh
$ reged  -x /mnt/win10/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM \
   'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM' \
   '\ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\4c1d96a0c133' /dev/stdout \
    | grep c8478c0b5dd0
"c8478c0b5dd0"=hex:a6,06,9a,01,2d,6c,1c,49,05,31,97,86,e3,98,67,5c
```

it not output to stdout, so use /dev/stdout.
it can't specify item name, so use grep.

### C. [hivexget](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hivexget.1.html)

apt install `libhivex-bin`

```
root@archiso ~ # hivexget /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM  'ControlSet001\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName'
"@"="mnmsrvc"
"ComputerName"="EPX-VIDYY"
```

### D. [hivexregedit](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hivexregedit.1.html)

apt install `libwin-hivex-perl`

```
root@archiso ~ # hivexregedit --export  /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM  'ControlSet001\Services\iaStorV'
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[\ControlSet001\services\iaStorV]
"DriverPackageId"=hex(1):69,00,61,00,73,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,76,00,2e,00,69,00,6e,00,66,00,5f,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,5f,00,6e,00,65,00,75,00,74,00,72,00,61,00,6c,00,5f,00,31,00,38,00,63,00,63,00,63,00,62,00,38,00,33,00,62,00,33,00,34,00,65,00,31,00,34,00,35,00,33,00,00,00
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"Group"=hex(1):53,00,43,00,53,00,49,00,20,00,4d,00,69,00,6e,00,69,00,70,00,6f,00,72,00,74,00,00,00
"ImagePath"=hex(2):5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,00,69,00,61,00,53,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,56,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Tag"=dword:00000019
"Type"=dword:00000001

[\ControlSet001\services\iaStorV\Parameters]
"BusType"=dword:00000008
"queuePriorityEnable"=dword:00000000


root@archiso ~ # hivexregedit --export  /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM  'ControlSet001\Services\iaStorV' > /tmp/bla.reg
root@archiso ~ # vim /tmp/bla.reg
root@archiso ~ # hivexregedit --merge /mnt/Windows/System32/config/SYSTEM /tmp/bla.reg
```

Comment: please add hivex. thanks.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/hivexget

Comment: @thomas I didn't try it yet, edit answer to improve are welcome : )