# How to check Windows version installed on Hard Drive?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

How do I check which version of Windows is installed on an old hard drive, from a Linux command line?

Answer (score 3):

"Offline NT Password & Registry Editor" ([chntpw](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/))

**chntpw** is a software utility for resetting or blanking local passwords used by Windows NT, 2000, XP, Vista, and 7. It also contains a simple registry editor and hex-editor with which the information contained in a registry file can be browsed and modified under linux/unix.

You can install it from terminal by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install chntpw
```

HIVE:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.

FOLDER LOCATION:

- **%SystemRoot%\System32\config**

FILENAME:

- **SOFTWARE**

[Is there a way to edit the Windows registry from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135200/is-there-a-way-to-edit-the-windows-registry-from-ubuntu)

[Access Windows Registry from Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/289955/access-windows-registry-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

One way which I discovered was to look in Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Windows and deduce from the default background which version of Windows it was. This seems like a very suboptimal solution though.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get other methods to work, and there is beauty in this simplicity!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Logman's answer, I did this:

```
sudo apt install chntpw
chntpw -e /path/to/windisk/Windows/System32/config/SOFTWARE
cat \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

and was told that the version was `Windows 10 Home`.

Additional details may be found through other keys. To list other keys in `CurrentVersion`,  while in `chntpw`, do

```
ls \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```